# Characterize the continuity of linear maps between Banach spaces in terms of continuous linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I solved a) and b). But I cant seem to get a grip of what characterizes the functionals for which we want continuity in the general case. Hints please!

[image: problem]

Comment: Hint #1: if posting an image, crop it so it is readable. . Hint #2: things like $(Mx)_k$ and $(Mx)(t)$ are really compositions of $M$ with a continuous linear functional on the target space.

Comment: @NormalHuman I've idenitied those as projection on n'th coordinate and evaluation at t,  but dont see how these two types of functionals are related. I understood that one could think of projection as eval at "n" given that we interpret an element of $\ell^{p}$ as a function from the naturals to the reals, but for a general banach space we might not even have  a domain for our elements. Thats why I left that idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The families of functionals mentioned in (a) and (b) have a property in common: they *separate* the points of the Banach space, meaning that for every nonzero element of the space the family contains a functional that does not vanish on that element.

In general, suppose $\mathcal F\subset Y^*$ is a family that separates the points of $Y$. Then a linear map $M:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ M$ is continuous for every $f\in \mathcal F$.

That was the hint. The proof is under spoilers.

> One direction is trivial. To prove the other, use the Closed Graph Theorem.

> Suppose $x_n\to x$ and $Mx_n\to y$; the goal is to show $Mx=y$. On one hand, $f(Mx_n)\to f(Mx)$ because $f\circ M$ is continuous; on the other, $f(Mx_n)\to f(y)$ because $Mx_n\to y$. So, $f(Mx-y)=0$ for all $f\in\mathcal F$, which implies $Mx-y=0$.

Comment: If the family seperate points does it mean that there is  a function that is nonzero on any $x$ and zero on the rest?

Comment: I defined what it means: $\forall x\in X\ \exists f\in \mathcal F$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$. This is all. "Zero on the rest" is absurd; if a continuous function is nonzero at one point, it's nonzero in a neighborhood.

Comment: Is your definition "weaker" then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_set ? Or is it equivalent? There is nothing saying all $f$ attain same nonzero value for all elements in your definition.

Comment: It is equivalent, because $x\ne y \iff x-y\ne 0$ and $f(x)\ne f(y) \iff f(x-y)\ne 0$. (By the way, I should have $\nabla x\in X\setminus \{0\}$ in the previous comment.)